# How to stop right click dead-locking Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash, deadlock

I have a very serious problem with Visual Studio 2008.
Occasionally when I right-click (for go to definition, set next statement etc) when I'm debugging, Visual Studio will just dead-lock and go into not responding mode.

Has anyone had the same problem? Does anyone know how to solve it?

**Edit:** I'm using SP1 with a couple of hot-fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue no longer occurs for me since I've moved to Windows7. If you're unfortunate to be stuck with Windows Vista still, I did discover that it only hung on right-click when waiting for the intellisense database to be built (see the bottom left corner for it's progress). The only "fix" I had was to wait for intellisense to stop building, then do a right-click.

Answer (score 7):

**Problem:** 
Signed Applications/dlls load slowly in Vista. Visual Studio IDE 'Hangs' on offline/non-internet-connected workstations. Without internet connectivity the certificate revocation check times out and causes applications to hang. When debugging/stepping through code dlls are loaded as needed and this is when the revocation check is attempted and the VS IDE becomes unresponsive.

**What this effects:** 
This effects all signed applications/dlls and is also the reason for Microsoft Word/Excel taking so long to open a simple document. Office applications, SQL Management Studio, Visual Studio, Web Applications that use a certificate.

**Fix:**
Disable checking of Publisher's Certificate Revocation

Via IE:

1. Go to Internet Options in IE 7
2. Then go to the Security Tab, scroll towards the bottom
3. Uncheck the 'Check for Publisher's Certificate Revocation' checkbox
4. Click OK

Via the registry:

1. Open regedit
2. Browse to the following key:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WinTrust\Trust Providers\Software Publishing
3. To disable the check: 
   Change the value of the State key to 146944 Decimal or 0x00023e00 Hexadecimal 
   To re-enable the check:
   Change the value of the State key to 146432 Decimal or 0x00023c00 Hexadecimal

**Alternate Fix:** 
Disable the Visual Studio Hosting Process:

1. Open a project in Visual Studio.
2. On the Project menu, click Properties.
3. Click the Debug tab.
4. Clear the Enable the Visual Studio hosting process check box.

Note: The Alternate Fix causes the loss of some debugging functionality.

Background: 
[Microsoft Connect Report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=343014)

Comment: What about IE9 in Win7? Didn't find this option.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a piece of code the other day, a very crazy template, and the latest VisualStudio would just hang if I placed my mouse over the templated code. It was surreal :)

Anyways you might have an issue like that and you might want to delete your intellisense database and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Try launching Visual Studio in [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(VS.80).aspx) to rule out problems with any extension installed.

Answer (score 2):

When debugging multi-threaded apps, sometimes I get a hang when breakpoint is hit.  And sometimes VS would hang (hourglass) when I tried to look at a variable by right-clicking on the variable within the code.

I googled and found a hint that explained, that when VS breaks, it evaluates all the variables in the locals and watch panes, in order to display them. But in threaded apps, this can cause deadlocks if the code takes locks when evaluating values, for example in property getters.

By closing the locals pane before I break, I avoided the hangs.

I'm not explaining this very well.  I tried googling again to find the original hint, but did not succeed.

It *may have been* this: [Why does Visual Studio stall while debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317678/why-does-visual-studio-stall-while-debugging/317807#317807).

Answer (score 2):

Exit Visual Studio and delete the .ncb file for the project.

Answer (score 0):

no, but it sounds like a bug. Report it to MS and they'll give you instructions how to get a debug setup going to send them information to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, have you applied the SP1?

I haven't had your exact issue, but I did have problems with it locking up for 15 seconds in debug mode (or when coming out of debug mode).  I found a blog post somewhere that suggested some possible fixes.

One of them was to go into IE 7 and open up Tools->Internet Options->Advanced Tab->Security section and uncheck the 'Check for publisher's certificate revocation' and 'check for server certificate revocation' (or at least the first one).  Once I did that, my lock-up woes were over.

Granted, my dev box isn't on the internet, so I didn't care much about most of those settings anyhow in IE.  Don't know if that is any help to you, but it certainly fixed my issues with VS 2008.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I find Visual Studio (VC9) locks up regularly when debugging multithread apps.  I usually have to reboot to get the system back.

Answer (score 0):

For me I found that VS was trying to open an IP that had expired for when I did some previous remote debugging. Check your Debugging setup under Tools-->Options-->Debugging--->Symbols
Make sure you don't have a bad path there.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution I know, but justification for moving my VC projects from VC2008 to VC2010- where Intellisense has been disabled. The recovery worked ok despite not having explicitly hit save for 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

> delete the .ncd and .suo files of the associated project.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/vcgeneral/thread/611c7f62-85f1-4294-9dc3-4dca29fe33da)

Answer (score -1):

Ah another big show stopper could be "ActiveDirectory". If this happens at your work and they use "ActiveDirectory" this can happen. Someone here claimed it was a bug with Google Toolbar, but I don't have solid evidence that Google is responsible or not.